# Kickstart fails on SSD disk

Tags: centos, ssd, kickstart

Trying to deploy a 2xSSD server (with mdraid level 1), errors on the 1st line:

```
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda,sdb
```

with the message "sda not found".

As the SSD is SATA3, shouldn't it be called via the standard sdX names?

The machine is physical (Tyan AFAIR), and I'm trying to deploy latest CentOS 5.x via TheForeman, which includes DHCP/TFTP and Puppet.

The disks are SanDisk Industrial/ Embedded SSD (32 GB), mounted via 2.5 to 3.5 adapter to server disk brackets and connected directly to the motherboard SATA ports

Comment: Is this a physical machine or virtualized somehow?

Comment: Are they connected to a SAS controller? maybe the device names are different?  Have a look at the dmesg output as suggested by EEAA.

Comment: Which **operating system** are you attempting this with? Which version of the OS? What type of server hardware? What specific SSDs are you using? What are they connected to? What installation media are you using? This is *so* little information to go on, it's nearly impossible to give proper answers.

Comment: Sorry, posted it quite in a hurry, updated above. That said I'm trying with another machine (Tyan shut down on me several times, probably due to overheating), will ask to close if it works.

Comment: Works fine (old machine was the culprit), asked to close.

Answer (score 2):

While `/dev/sdX` is the most common, I've also seen `/dev/xvdX`, especially with some configurations of the Xen hypervisor.

Regardless, just look through the output of `dmesg` after boot, and you'll find the device names listed as the kernel enumerates them.

Comment: They won't be xvdX unless it's inside a xen guest.  But the dmesg output should show the correct device names.

Comment: @Matt - good point. I clarified that above.

Comment: Seems good idea, I will just boot Live CD and check there.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of better information (e.g. OS version, hardware involved, SSD brand, installation method/media), let's assume you're installing CentOS or a Redhat derivative from USB (or USB-attached CD/DVD) or IPMI virtual media. That could impact your SCSI device naming.

You can run a manual installation and scan for the devices that show up. Or you could break out of the installer at the point of the error (go to another virtual terminal) and see which devices were detected. Even an `fdisk -l` at that point would give you an idea of what the installer found.